# Magento 2: How to Add Custom CSS And Js and also Images in which Folder

Tags: magento2

Magento 2: How to Add Custom CSS And Js and also Images in which Folder. Please Share also a folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any custom **css**, **js** and **images** to the below location of your theme:

- For CSS: app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/
- For JS: app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/js/
- For Images: app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/images/